# LoopBack & Node.JS (Client side) - How to use the token provided by LoopBack on the client side?

Tags: node.js, server, client, token, loopbackjs

I started using LoopBack. But one thing I don't understand is this "**token**".

I am struggling with using this token (provided by the LoopBack-Explorer). I simply don't know **where** to use it on the client-side (NodeJS + VueJS).

#### So my question is:

How (and where) can I use this token to securely **get** data from and **post** data to my backend?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the token value in the query string of whatever endpoint you are querying as the value of `access_token`.

e.g.

```
GET api/Projects?access_token=Yuu8iBDaE4lz9hTB49hTTjnlTRGake7ZVJ3eOwRIoLCu4N52dQoDsCm4uFsCREy1
```

Unless you have configured your loopback server to use cookies instead, but I suspect this is not the case.

If you are using the Explorer you can click on the "Try it out!" button without any parameters and check the "Current URL" field to see what is the explorer doing.

In this case you can login via Explorer, copy the token to the top right side field and click "Set Access Token" and then you can find out how exactly are the queries being done for a particular endpoint.

Comment: LoopBack serves my model data although I do not include the token! Do I have to setup something in LoopBack to make it "hide" the data?

Comment: Ok, so [you probably need to read this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html) if you haven't enabled access controls. Basically what you do is setup the per-model's permissions you want to grant/deny to each user Role you have (via ACLs), and then when a user of a specific role logs in, they will be given an access token. This token is then required to do requests that are protected via the model's ACLs. 

So for example, certain GETs you can make public (i.e. no token needed) while requiring the POST requests to provide a valid token.